# TypeORM make COUNT query on table which maps two tables together

Tags: mysql, database, nestjs, typeorm

I have two entities `Model` and `Video` where `Video` basically store information about videos and `Model` store information about model. Because each video can have multiple models and each model can have multiple video entities looks like this:

#### How my entites and tables looks like:

```
// Video Entity
@Entity()
export class Video {
  @PrimaryGeneratedColumn()
  id?: number; 

  @Column({ charset: 'utf8mb4', collation: 'utf8mb4_unicode_ci' })
  name: string;

  @Column({ type: 'text', charset: 'utf8mb4', collation: 'utf8mb4_unicode_ci' })
  description: string;

  @ManyToMany((type) => Model)
  @JoinTable()
  models: Model[];
}


// Model Entity
@Entity()
export class Model {

  @PrimaryGeneratedColumn()
  id?: number; 

  @Column()
  name: string;

  @Column()
  code: string;
}
```

Because there is relation `@ManyToMany` between model and video TypeORM also created one extra table for connecting this two. Table name is `video_models_model` and it looks like this:

```
+-----------+---------+
| videoId   | modelId |
+===========+=========+
| 1         | 107     |
+-----------+---------+
| 2         | 142     |
+-----------+---------+
| 3         | 91      |
+-----------+---------+
```

#### What I need:

Based on modelId I need to find out `COUNT()` of videos.
In regular query language it  would be something like:

```
SELECT model.*, COUNT(model_videos.videoId) as totalVideos FROM model as model
LEFT JOIN `video_models_model` `model_videos` ON `model_videos`.`modelId`=`model`.`id` 
WHERE model.id = 1;
```

#### What I tried:

This is how regular query would looks like:

```
this.modelRepository
  .createQueryBuilder('model')  
  .where('model.id = :id', { id: id })        
  .getOne();
```

so what I did was added to `Model` entity

```
  @ManyToMany(type => Video)
  @JoinTable()
  videos: Video[];
```

and after that I tried

```
this.modelRepository
  .createQueryBuilder('model')
  .leftJoin('model.videos', 'videos')
  .select('COUNT(videos)', 'totalVideos')  
  .where('model.id = :id', { id: id })        
  .getOne();
```

But it didn't work for me at all pluis it created one additional table named `model_videos_video` with `modelId` and `videoId` columns. So basically duplicate `video_models_model` table.

Is there any way how to make that easy query with TypeORM?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I found out that I have to change my entities to make them bi-directional so:
Video Entity:

```
@Entity()
export class Video {
  @PrimaryGeneratedColumn()
  id?: number; 

  @Column({ charset: 'utf8mb4', collation: 'utf8mb4_unicode_ci' })
  name: string;

  @Column({ type: 'text', charset: 'utf8mb4', collation: 'utf8mb4_unicode_ci' })
  description: string;

  @ManyToMany(type => Model, model => model.videos)
  @JoinTable()
  models: Model[];
}
```

Model Entity:

```
@Entity()
export class Model {

  @PrimaryGeneratedColumn()
  id?: number; 

  @Column()
  name: string;

  @Column()
  code: string;

  @ManyToMany(type => Video, video => video.models)
  videos: Video[];
}
```

And after that I make query like this:

```
this.modelRepository
  .createQueryBuilder('model')
  .loadRelationCountAndMap('model.videoCount', 'model.videos')
  .where('model.id = :id', { id: id })        
  .getOne();
```